# Can't combine a hook and a function in onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. This is a 3 step registration form. In the last step - StepThree, I've been trying to have a hook - handleDateChange and a function - HandleUserInfo work on one click and send the registration form to the database. In the previous version this code was split into two steps, in (old)StepThree you had the date of birth and in the last one (old StepFour) you had the photo upload.I've joined them but it doesn't work.In my file (new) StepThree.js I have the following code

```
const StepThree = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(
    new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54')
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('isInsideSteps', 3);
  }, []);

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  // Old Step 4

  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const [showErrDlg, setShowErrDlg] = useState(false);
  const [img, setImg] = useState({ urlString: '', file: {} });

  const uploadImage = (event) => {
    setImg({
      urlString: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
      file: event.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  const onDialogClose = () => {
    setShowErrDlg(false);
  };

  const completeSubmit = (imgUrl) => {
    User.createProfile({
      img: imgUrl,
      token: user.token,
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      account: { _id: user.account._id },
      ...user.account
    })
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.removeItem('isInsideSteps');
        setUserData(res.data.account, setUser);
        history.push('/');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setShowErrDlg(true);
      });
  };

  const sendToBucket = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', img.file);
    Files.upload_image(formData).then((res) => {
      completeSubmit(res.image_url);
    });
  };

  const handleUserInfo = () => {
    const updatedUserInfo = {
      dob: selectedDate
    };
    updateUser(updatedUserInfo);

    history.push('/');
  };
```

When I put the **handleUserInfo** function in the onClick event in the **Submit Button** the data from previous steps doesn't send but the date of birth. On the other hand when I put **handleDateChange** (like in the code below) everything sends but the date of birth. This is the pertinent code in "return".

```
<>
      <Navbar justImage />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm" alignItems="center">
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <div className={classes.title}>Register</div>
          <div className={classes.textDescription}>
            Upload a profile picture
          </div>
        </div>
        <form
          noValidate
          onSubmit={(e) => sendToBucket(e, handleUserInfo)}
          className={classes.uploadImage}
        >
          <div className={classes.marginBottom}>
            {img.urlString !== '' ? (
              <img src={img.urlString} className={classes.image} alt="" />
            ) : (
              <div>
                <AccountCircleIcon className={classes.userIcon} />
              </div>
            )}

            <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              style={{ display: 'none' }}
              id="raised-button-file"
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => uploadImage(e)}
            />
            <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
              <SubmitButton type="button" variant="outlined" component="span">
                Choose File
              </SubmitButton>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <div className={classes.paragraphDob}>Enter your date of birth</div>
          </div>
          <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
              className={classes.dataPicker}
              disableToolbar
              disableFuture
              variant="inline"
              format="MM/dd/yyyy"
              margin="normal"
              id="date-picker-inline"
              label="Date of brith"
              value={selectedDate}
              onChange={handleDateChange}
              KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date'
              }}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

          <Grid container className={classes.marginTop}>
            <Grid item xs>
              <SubmitButton
                type="submit"
                value="Continue"
                onClick={handleDateChange}
                variant="contained"
                disabled={img.urlString === ''}
              >
                Complete
              </SubmitButton>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs className={classes.backHomeAlign}>
              <Link to="/register/step2" className={classes.backHomeLink}>
                Back to previous
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
```

I've tried writing one function and including these two, a promise function and generally putting them in other functions/hooks. Nothing works. Any hep much appreciated.

EDIT: I added the relevant code in the return statement. The form, in Step Three is supposed to send the uploaded picture and date of birth input. With this code it send the uploaded picture and but not the date of birth.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do with the code, or what the issue is. Can you edit to include a relevant [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've better and more complete context? From what I can gather it seems you don't prevent the default form submission action from occurring, and there seems likely a state update that you are expecting to be immediate. React state updates are asynchronously processed.

Comment: I have uploaded the rest of the relevant code. I'm not sure if that helps. The form is supposed to send to the database the uploaded picture and the date of birth. For now it only sends the uploaded picture. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I switched this:

```
const handleUserInfo = () => {
const updatedUserInfo = {
  dob: selectedDate
};
updateUser(updatedUserInfo);

history.push('/');
```

};

To that and it worked:

```
  const updatedUserInfo = {
    dob: selectedDate
  };
  updateUser(updatedUserInfo);
```

Meaning I had too many OnClick events.